# ICS like spinner in previous versions of android

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to the spinner to look like as in ICS in all the previous versions of android above 2.2. Is there any project or samples you know ? I came through a project [HoloEverywhere](https://github.com/ChristopheVersieux/HoloEverywhere)

But it contains lot of change , which makes my application huge in size. So you know any simple changes that i can use. Custom layut can help me but how can i get the ICS resource ?

Comment: create your own style and background for the spinner, that would be much simpler

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Download any support library and include in your project build path

then instead of `Spinner` in the `xml` use something like

```
<com.name.internal.widget.IcsSpinner
....
/>
```

[image]

otherwise design a custom spinner yourself. But if there are many things you want like ICS to be implemented in some lower level API better do it using support libraries.

You can get support libraries for respective APIs' at the developers site:

http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/support-library.html

or better you download it from here, which also includes `ActionBarSherlock`

http://actionbarsherlock.com/

Comment: Can you tell, where can i get that support library?

Comment: I already have android-support-v4.jar , but still its throwing error like,Class Not found Exception

Comment: thats because you are giving a wrong name to your spinner. please check the name you are giving. If you are using ActionBarSherlock library you must name it "com.actionbarsherlock.internal.widget.IcsSpinner". Similarly check the library for the name of the class you must use

Comment: That being said, there is no ice cream sandwich spinner view in the support library, it's Actionbarsherlocks work.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to set ICS style background for you spinner and for sources try to download >=API 14 source which contains images which you can use.

Answer (score 0):

I needed this also but did not wan't to use ActionBarSherlock, I'm using android support library, and also did not wan't to use list navigation mode. See full solution here https://stackoverflow.com/a/21187762/3206751