# Android Spinner look and feel like ICS

Tags: android

I like the look and feel of the Spinner in Android ICS. I support a minimum of android 2.1 so i want the Spinner to have an ICS look on the Android 2.1. Is this possible.

Kind Regards,

Comment: Possible Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12365508/ics-like-spinner-in-previous-versions-of-android

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with Android Support Library.
Download any support library and include in your project build path.

Comment: I have had a look at support v4 library but there is no Spinner or not Switch in it ?

Answer (score 2):

Yes this is possible. You can make a custom style for your Spinner and set the drawable to the spinner style of ICS. You can find the 9-patch drawables here:

EDIT: project was moved:
https://github.com/Prototik/HoloEverywhere/tree/master/library/res/drawable-mdpi

Comment: Can you point out exactly which elements i have to use. I am using the compatibility pack v4 in my project. How do i use this for my Spinner ?

Comment: This is the XML Christophe is using: https://github.com/ChristopheVersieux/HoloEverywhere/blob/master/library/res/drawable/spinner_background_holo_dark.xml

Comment: https://github.com/Prototik/HoloEverywhere/blob/master/library/res/drawable/spinner_background_holo_dark.xml